# Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9

Tags: memory-leaks, typescript, ios-simulator, nativescript

I'm experinecing 'Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9' error and can't run my app. I read that it may be due to the memory leaks or if it's taking too long to launch the app. To be honest, it is taking too long to launch my app on IOS simulator. I'm using the '*tns run ios --emulator*' command, tried following commands as well:

1) Call *tns run ios --justlaunch*

2) Call *tns livesync ios --watch*

Still having the same issue. Please, help me to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this problem has been related with this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/1816)